# Another wifi dropping thread!

Tags: wireless, disconnect

I am using Ubuntu 13.10 on the new Intel NUC i3 with the Intel Centrino Advanced-N 6235  wireless adapter.  It's a fresh install and I only added XBMC for Linux to it.  My problem is that the wifi connection keeps dropping every 10mins or so, and when it does, my wifi network disappears from the avaiable wifi networks list and there is no way to connect back to it.  The only way to make the network available again, is to completely  delete the network and then add it again from scratch, entering the password and everything.  The other way is to reboot.  Other than that the network  is just not detected  at all by the system.    Once I am reconnected,  it will work for another 10mins before it drops again, and so on. 
This is my home wifi network, and I have several other devices connected to the wifi without any issues.
I read some other posts where they said to do  sudo apt-get update..and also  disabling ipV6 and setting MTU to 1500, I tried that but it didn't fix the issue.
I would really appreciate if I can get some trouble shooting assistance with this issue.  I am quite new to Linux so I'd appreciate a detailed walk thru.

Thanks a lot in advance and looking forward to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with this device, even in Windows. Please see: https://communities.intel.com/message/192239#192239 There are several complaints as well at ubuntuforums.org. Some things that may be helpful are to disable 802.11N capability. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
modprobe -r iwldvm
modprobe -r iwlwifi
modprobe iwlwifi
exit
```

Some users seem to be helped by explicitly setting the regulatory domain from here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2  For instance, if your country code is ES, then:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Right above the line exit 0, add a new line:

```
iw reg set ES
```

Of course, substitute your code here. After a reboot, is there any improvement?

Should you wish to re-enable N speeds, which may bring back the instability, please do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
```

Remove the line you added:

```
options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1
```

Proofread, save and close gedit. Upon reboot, N capabilities will be available again.